# WCF Json returns null values for DataMember elements

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a ws working ok when I tried it using a browser, I mean, all te correct values are returning.

But when I try to do it from my client APP using POST method, it doesn't matter what the server does, the client get nulls values.

This is my returning class:

```
[DataContract]
public class ResponseModel
{
    [DataMember(Name = "exito", Order = 0)]
    public bool Exito { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "logout", Order = 1)]
    public bool LogOut { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "frase", Order = 2)]
    public String Frase { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my servicecontract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "HelloWorld")]
    ResponseModel HelloWorld();
}
```

Comment: post your web.config please

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted your implementation of `ResponseModel HelloWorld();` and how you are making request so I will try to make guess!

If you are posting some data to your service, you need to make it in **XML** or **JSON** for the method of **POST**. For this change your **ServiceContract** like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "HelloWorld")]
    ResponseModel HelloWorld();
}
```

I have added **RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json** if you want to make request in JSON. For **XML** make it **RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.XML**.

Now when you make request, then add data in **JSON/XML**. 
If you can post your request format then more appropriate suggestions can be made. For sending data in **POST** request, you have to set request header **Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8**. 
I hope this will help.